# How can I move from an optimal feasible solution to an optimal basic feasible solution?

Tags: linear-programming

I have the following problem: \begin{align}\max&\quad c^T x\\\text{s.t.}&\quad Ax=b\\&\quad x\ge0\end{align}

The matrix $A$ is $m\times n$, where $m<n$.

I have an optimal solution $x^*$ in which all variables are non-zero.
I know that there must exist another optimal solution $x^{**}$, a "basic feasible solution", in which at most $m$ variables are non-zero.

Given $x^*$, is there an algorithm for finding $x^{**}$ using polynomially-many arithmetic operations? (I know that $x^{**}$ can be found using the Simplex method, but I am looking for a polynomial-time algorithm).

Comment: See https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=kEOeI2gAAAAJ&cstart=20&pagesize=80&citation_for_view=kEOeI2gAAAAJ:KlAtU1dfN6UC

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK I saw this paper before, but so far I did not manage to understand the algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the constraints are equations, solve the linear system $$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\\
c^{\prime}
\end{array}\right]y=0
$$for any nonzero solution $y$. You can look for an eigenvector with nonzero eigenvalue, or just tack on the equation $r^\prime y = 1$ for some vector $r$ randomly generated from a continuous distribution (e.g., all components uniform over $[0,1]$). Solving a linear system should be polynomial time. Now look for the largest scalar $t$ such that $x^* + t y\ge 0$ (and, if that is unbounded, repeat using $-y$ in place of $y$). Replace $x*$ with $x^* + ty$ for that value of $t$, drop the variable $x_i$ which just became 0 from the problem, and repeat until you are at a corner point (BFS).

Comment: What is $c'$ - is it the same as $c$?

Comment: I guess it's $c$ transposed.

Comment: Yes, it is $c$ as a row vector.

Comment: Ah, I see. So $A y=0$ and $c'y=0$. So, for any scalar $t$, $A(x^*+ty)=Ax^*+tAy=b+0 = b$ and $c'(x^*+ty)=c'x^*+tc'y=c'x^*$, so $x^*+ty$ is still a feasible and optimal solution to the original problem. But why is it certain that some variable $x_i$ will become 0?
2nd question: when repeating the process, how do I prevent $x_i$ from becoming nonzero again - should I add an explcit constraint $x_i=0$?

Comment: First question: since $y\neq 0$, either the $+y$ or $-y$ direction must contain at least one negative component. If that component has index $i$, then $x_i$ is decreasing and, if you go far enough, must reach 0. The only thing preventing you from going that far would be some other component going to 0 first.

Comment: Second question: This is why I wrote that you should *drop* the variable $x_i$ that became 0 (eliminate its column from $A$) and work with the the reduced dimensional vector. Adding $x_i = 0$ to the system of equations would be equivalent mathematically. I suspect it would also be slightly slower, but I doubt the speed difference would be meaningful to you.

Comment: There is still an issue: the matrix at the left-hand side has $m+1$ rows -- $m$ rows of $A$ plus one row of $c'$. So, once we have $m+1$ variables remaining, we might not find a nonzero solution for $y$. What do we do to get a solution with only $m$ nonzero variables?

Comment: If there is no nonzero solution, you must be at a corner point (BFS). At the end of each step you have a feasible solution, with an increasing number of variables fixed at zero, whose objective value matches the optimal value. We know there is an optimal BFS $x^*$. If the current solution $\hat{x}$ is not a BFS, then the vector $y=x^* - \hat{x}$ is zero in all components where $\hat{x}$ and $x^*$ are both zero, solves the reduced system, and is nonzero.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a basic solution such that

$$
c^T x^{**} \leq c^T x^{*}
$$

using at most n-m simplex pivots. That is strongly polynomial time.

Any decent recent text book about the simplex method should teach you that.
You may also be able to figure it out based on description of the primal simplex method in [my note](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.229.3959&rep=rep1&type=pdf). (You just try to pivot each nonzero nonbasic variable in the basis. It is decreased if the reduced cost is negative otherwise it is increased.)

Comment: Maybe you mean to add the following constraint to the original problem: $c^T x = c^T x^{*}$, and then just find a basic feasible solution (regardless of the optimization)?

Comment: Fixed some typos. The algorithm find a solution that is at least as good as the initial solution in terms of the objective value.

Comment: OK, but there is now an additional constraint. So the number of nonzeros in a BFS of the new system might be $m+1$?